# GARCH Maximum Likelihood Model in Statsmodels (GenericLikelihoodModel)

Tags: python, statsmodels, mle

I am typing up the estimation procedure for a Structural GARCH model using `GenericLikelihoodModel` in `statsmodels`. To start with a simple likelihood function I am trying to code up a ML-estimator for the GARCH(1,1) model and expand to a GJR-GARCH(1,1,1) before turning towards the full Structural-GARCH model.

My starting point is the Maximum Likelihood estimator of Probit models in [this link](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/generic_mle.html). The problem is that I don't understand the formulation of the likelihood function in the example based on the variable `q`. 
The likelihood function for the Probit model given in this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit_model#Maximum_likelihood_estimation) does not look like the one specified in the code line `return stats.norm.logcdf(q*np.dot(exog, params)).sum()`

The estimated parameters in the tutorial code coincide with the Probit model from `statsmodel`. Hence, I believe the code is correct I just do not understand the reformulation of the likelihood function through the variable `q`. Can anybody clarify the mathematical intuition behind the log-likelihood function in the line `return stats.norm.logcdf(q*np.dot(exog, params)).sum()`?

Comment: q is the sign coding, +1 or -1, for the response, and AFAIR it uses symmetry of normal distribution. Then, this can be rewritten to the standard formula for Probit.

Comment: Thank you @Josef! Is there a general trick to reformulate the likelihood function as in the example, or is it all about seeing the smart way separately for each likelihood function?

Comment: It's specific to each likelihood function, or to classes of distributions with similar properties.Those reformulation often come from textbooks, articles or documentation of other packages.

Comment: Thanks again @Josef! Can you point me in any direction as to the reformulation of the likelihood in a GARCH(1,1) model?

Comment: You can look at the code in the arch package https://pypi.org/project/arch/ I haven't looked at GARCH in many years.